# Equality Operator In Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

On an edit form, I am trying to pass value of selected dropdown by marking the `selected` as `true` if one id matches another. The ids match but I don't seem to be getting a `true` result.

```
select(name='categoryId' id="category")
    each category in categories
        option(value=category._id selected=(entry.category._id === category._id))= `${category.mainCategory}`
```

I've even tried to use `` `${entry.category._id === category._id}` ``

I changed the operator from `===` to `==`

If I try to convert the ids to numbers it gives me a `NaN` output

None of them worked.. I always get a false value and I've double checked and compared if the values are equal and they are. They are both strings coming from mongodb.

Any advise would be appreciated